# MAMP giving 404 error - file not found

Tags: php, forms, http-status-code-404, mamp

I'm using mamp to test a multi-page form, and the first page (amd3.html) works fine. When the form directs to amd4.html, it says file not found. They are both in the same folder, and when I select amd4.html by itself from a list of files under MAMP folders, without amd3.html, it works fine. I noticed that when amd3 directs to amd4, it's missing an http://, and maybe that's why it's not working? How can I fix this?

filepath for amd3.html: http:// localhost:8888/website/amb3.html (works)

filepath for amd4.php: http:// localhost:8888/website/amb4.php (directs to this)

Error message:

Not Found

The requested URL /website/amb4.php was not found on this server.

Comment: You use amd4.html, amb4.php... I can't follow ! Can you post the source of your form ?

Comment: amd3.html is the first part of my form which is strictly html, amd4.php is my 2nd part of the form that has php involved related to amd3.html

Comment: We're going to need code snippets if you want us to figure this out. How to you link to the second page ? (amd4.html)

Comment: <form action="amb4.php" method="post" id="repeated"> -> this is how i connected to amd4.php from amd3.html

Comment: Do you have an amb4.php? From your description I only see an amb4.html. You will need to rename your html file or create a new php file.

Comment: Ok, so normally, amd3.html and amd4.php should be in the same directory, are they ?

Comment: oh sorry, I meant amd4.php and yes that is what it's named. Yes they are in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

The error is obvious:

```
<form action="amb4.php" method="post" id="repeated">
```

Is calling amb4.php file instead of amd4.php, that must be called. Maybe, you need to write:

```
<form action="amd4.php" method="post" id="repeated">
```

?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand?

Comment: @JohnSmith Do you have .htaccess, that redirects from amb files to amd? Sorry, you didn't posted it. And I made my conclusions, based upon Apache error message, you provided.

Comment: @JohnSmith Great, that you saw it.